# remove lines that match column condition in Unix/bash

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, pipe

What's the best way in bash to do a quick one liner to filter out all lines from a tab separated file if the `N`th field has the string `s` in it? example:

```
$ cat myfile 
A  B_crop  C
A  X_mock  D

$ cat myfile | filter -V -c 2 -s "crop"
A  X_mock  D
```

the made up command `filter` takes a column number (1-based) `-c`, a string `-s`, and keeps only lines that have the string in the given column. If it's passed `-V` then like `grep`, it excludes lines that don't have the string is a substring in that column number. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're wanting exclusions based on column, I would use `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "crop" { print $0 }' myfile
```

The `$2` says compare using column 2.  To implement the `-V` functionality, use `!=` rather than `==`.

You can also use regex checking to check the substring:

```
awk '$2 ~ /crop/ { print $0 }' myfile
```

Regex matching can also be negated with `!~`.

Comment: But that doesn't check for substring right? I want to see if `crop` in somewhere in the string corresponding to the column

Comment: @user248237dfsf You can pipe to awk: `echo "abc" | awk "{print $0}"`.  You wouldn't want to in this case because it's a waste, but you can certainly do it.